# Is storing data and a mutable pointer to that data in a struct safe?

Tags: rust, ffi, unsafe

Let's consider a Rust wrapper library around a C library. This C library defines a struct and uses it as a mutable pointer throughout it's API.

The Rust wrapper defines the following struct with `ptr` pointing at `data`.

```
struct Wrapper {
    data: struct_from_c_t,
    ptr: *mut struct_from_c_t,
}
```

If all uses of this pointer are made within the `Wrapper` struct's lifetime, what other potential issues can I run into when using this pointer in unsafe code ?

Is dereference and use of this pointer always safe in this construct?

For detailed context, the goal is to be able to call FFI functions using this pointer from functions borrowing `Wrapper` non-mutably.

Comment: As far as I know what you are doing is undefined behavoir. You have to use an [Unsafecell](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html) to achieve it. But I'm not very experienced with FFIs so this is not an answer ;)

Comment: Thanks, not taking this as an answer but I will definitely take a look at UnsafeCell to see if I can use it to make a safe wrapper.

Comment: If you want to know anything about FFI, read the [rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html)

Comment: I see no reason to go to `UnsafeCell`. That's used for building your own abstractions, but existing abstractions are sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is generally a **bad idea** and it can go wrong *very* easily.

First, go read [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423) for an in-depth explanation about why safe Rust prevents this construct at compile time.

TL;DR, if you *ever* move the `Wrapper` struct, the pointer will be invalid. Dereferencing it will cause undefined behavior (a bad thing).

If you can ensure that either of:

1. The `Wrapper` is never moved.
2. The `ptr` is updated every time you move the struct.

Then the pointer will be valid and safe to dereference (assuming all the other caveats about unsafe code are upheld).

---

What's worse is that there's no *reason* to keep the pointer in the first place; you can take a reference to a value and convert it into a pointer whenever you need:

```
extern "C" {
    fn ffi_fn(data: *mut struct_from_c_t);
}

struct Wrapper {
    data: struct_from_c_t,
}

impl Wrapper {
    fn do_thing(&mut self) {
        unsafe { ffi_fn(&mut self.data) }
    }
}
```

> from functions borrowing `Wrapper` non-mutably

Without context, this seems like a dubious decision, but Rust has tools for interior mutability:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Wrapper {
    data: RefCell<struct_from_c_t>,
}

impl Wrapper {
    fn do_thing(&self) {
        unsafe { ffi_fn(&mut *self.data.borrow_mut()) }
    }
}
```

Comment: The struct is still mutably borrowed but I think it's a mistype (I can't edit your pose since stackoverflow request at least 6 characters modification). The RefCell example seems fine. Is there something to worry about with unsafe usage of RefCell ? (the doc doesn't mention anything)

Comment: No, `RefCell` will panic and stop your program if you ever attempt to get two aliased mutable references, ensuring your program's memory safety.